# Fusion of multiple Occupancy Grids from different sensors

Tags: c++, algorithm, transformation, ros

I'm doing a project in ROS, where I have to make a robot navigate in the environment using a dynamic map built using data from his sensors.

Note: I don't have to store every map I build.

I have to wait data from every sensor and then create a new map every X milliseconds. A request for this project is that I have to build an Occupancy Grid for each sensor and then fuse them to make the robot decide his next direction and velocity.

By now I have created the Occupancy Grids from an Hokuyo sensor and from a Kinect2. I'm trying to fuse them by adding the value of each cell and it works quite well. The problem is that the same wall is repeated, a bit traslated to the right.

How can I compute the transformation between the two Occupancy Grids in a efficient way, even when the two Occupancy Grids have nothing in common (i.e. I'm not near the wall).

Comment: You have to calibrate the sensors. In the easiest case, you can specify a constant transformation matrix (assuming that the sensors are fixed on some kind of platform).

Comment: [Convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) and/or [cross-correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation) are the mathematical approach to this task. A more heuristic approach would be to compute the [root-mean-square (RMS) error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) between the two data sets, and then apply a transform to one of the data sets to see if you can reduce the RMS error. In proper buzzwords, use a [hill climbing algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_climbing) to minimize the RMS error.